# How to break url into multiple string parts

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I have a url that is hold the complete path of my SSRS Report . In C# i want to break the url in multiple string

```
http://Mydatabase-live/ReportServer?%2fADMIN%2fSTATS+-+SCHEDULE&TEAMNM=2015 TERRIER JV&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=PDF
```

Here i want to break this url into part-1  `http://Mydatabase-live/ReportServer` part-2 `ADMIN/STATS-SCHEDULE` and part-3 `TEAMNM`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought about this and one way to do it is to define some delimiters for the program to know where to break the URL.

Before we do this, we need to replace the special characters first.

So let's start:

```
string searchFor;
string replaceWith;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // First we need to replace the special characters:
    ReplaceSubstrings replace = new ReplaceSubstrings();
    string s = "http://Mydatabase-live/ReportServer?%2fADMIN%2fSTATS+-+SCHEDULE&TEAMNM=2015 TERRIER JV&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=PDF";

    // We need to replace:
    // "%2f" with "/"
    // "+-+" with "-"

    // using System.Text.RegularExpressions
    replace.searchFor = "%2f";
    replace.replaceWith = "/";
    s = Regex.Replace(s, replace.searchFor);

    replace.searchFor = "+-+";
    replace.replaceWith = "-";
    s = Regex.Replace(s, replace.searchFor);

    // Your URL will now look like this:

    Console.WriteLine(s);
    // Output: http://Mydatabase-live/ReportServer?/ADMIN/STATS-SCHEDULE&TEAMNM=2015 TERRIER JV&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=PDF

    // Add the delimiters
    char[] delimiters = {'?', '&', '='};
    string[] words = s.Split(delimiters);

    foreach (string s in words)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
    // Output:
    // http://Mydatabase-live/ReportServer
    // /ADMIN/STATS-SCHEDULE
    // TEAMNM
    // 2015 TERRIER JV
    // rs:Command
    // Render
    // rs:Format
    // PDF

    // Keep the console window open in debug mode.
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Your URL will be separated in much more places than you specified, but this is how you should do it. You could delete the last part from the string where the first `=` sign is located, and then execute the string separation.

I hope this helped you.

Comment: what is  ReplaceSubstrings replace = new ReplaceSubstrings();

Comment: It's used to create objects and invoke constructors. It's equivalent with: `Class1 obj  = new Class1();`

Answer (score 1):

This is dynamic way of splitting the URL using Uri Class.
Uri class has the feature to get absolute path,query and etc. You can use them and construct your requirement.

```
        string path = "http://Mydatabase-live/ReportServer?%2fADMIN%2fSTATS+-+SCHEDULE&TEAMNM=2015 TERRIER JV&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=PDF";
        Uri uri = new Uri(path);
        Console.WriteLine(uri.AbsolutePath); //Absolute path
        Console.WriteLine(uri.Query); //Query
```